# Proving that $\frac {(n+1)n(n-1)...(n-i)}{i+1}$ can be used as the summ of $k^h$

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

I have previously proved that $$\sum_{k=i}^{n} k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots(k-i+1) = \frac{(n+1)\cdot n\cdot (n-1)\cdots(n-i+1)}{i+1}$$

From here I am supposed to show that the formula above can be used to compute the sum of $k^h$, for example, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$, starting with $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
I cannot figure out the connection between these and do not know where to start...

Comment: Well but this is false! If the exponent is $\geq 2$ and $n=1$ that expression is always equal to zero.

Comment: @Kandinskij; What is false here excatly?

Comment: Try $h=2$ and $n=1$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be used.

Example with $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1+1)$

$=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1)) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}k$

$=(\sum_{k=2}^{n}k(k-1)) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}k$ ( means that $i = 2$)

$=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{3} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$=\frac{(n+1)n(2(n-1) + 3)}{6}$

$=\frac{(n+1)n(2n+1)}{6}$

---

Example with $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1+1)(k-2+2)$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k((k-1)(k-2) + 2(k-1)+(k-2)+2)$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k((k-1)(k-2) + 3k-2)$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1)(k-2) + 3\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 - 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$

$=\sum_{k=3}^{n}k(k-1)(k-2) + 3\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 - 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$ ( means that $i=3$)

$=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}{4} + 3\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - 2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$=\frac{n^2 (n + 1)^2}{4}$

---

Same way in higher power

Comment: What was $i$ in $$(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1))$$, that is for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2
$

Comment: @Aristarchus_ $i$ is length, so $i = 2$

Comment: RIght, this is the part that I do not get completely, what does it mean when the coefficient $k$ is equal to the lower limit $i$ in the above expression. You say that $i$ is length, but of what exactly? Isn't it the case that $i$ is a fixed number, while $k$ varies...?

Comment: @Aristarchus_ note that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k-1)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}k(k-1)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}k(k-2+1)$. It should now be clear that $i=2$.

Comment: nothing about $k$, it's about k's power $h$, or the number of multipliers. for $h=2$, the sum part is $k(k-1)$, so the $i = 2$, for $h=3$, the sum part is $k(k-1)(k-2)$, so the $i = 3$, for $h=4$, the sum part is $k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)$, so the $i = 4$,... and so on

Comment: Yes, The first few terms of the summation will be zero, so removing these terms will give you the equation with $i$ that you proved.

Answer (score 3):

It is convenient to use the *[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)* notation
\begin{align*}
k^{\underline{i}}:=k(k-1)\cdots (k-i+1)
\end{align*}

With this notation OPs identity can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=i}^nk^{\underline{i}}=\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{i+1}}}{i+1}
\end{align*}

> and since summands with $1\leq k<i$ are zero we can also write
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_i(n):=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\underline{i}}=\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{i+1}}}{i+1}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> We can now iteratively use $S_i(n), i=1,2,3,\ldots $ to calculate
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^nk^i
> \end{align*}

**Case $i=1$:**

Since $k=k^{\underline{1}}$ we obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n k}=S_1(n)=\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{2}}}{2}
\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}\left(n+1\right)n}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Case $i=2$:**

Since $k^2=k(k-1)+k=k^{\underline{2}}+k^{\underline{1}}$ we obtain from (1) and (2)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}&=S_2(n)+S_ 1(n)=\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{3}}}{3}+\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{2}}}{2}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{3}+\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{6}\left(2n^2+3n^2+n\right)}
\end{align*}

This way we can iteratively calculate $\sum_{k=1}^n k^i, i=3,4,\ldots$. Here it is useful to know that
\begin{align*}
k^i=\sum_{j=0}^i\begin{Bmatrix} i \\ j \end{Bmatrix} k^{\underline{j}}
\end{align*}
with $\begin{Bmatrix} i \\ j \end{Bmatrix}$ the *[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition)*.

**Note:** The sum formula (1) is a discrete analogon to
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^xt^i\,dt=\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}
\end{align*}
which is a main theme in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493382/finite-power-sum-derivation/4499396#4499396)* .

Comment: Clever! Thank you

Comment: @Aristarchus_: You're welcome. :-)